# How to merge two PoshWSUS objects in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, merge, powershell-3.0

$a and $b are lists with objects with two values
I want to make one $ab list merged by the same name value
This is my code

```
Import-Module PoshWSUS

Connect-PSWSUSServer -WsusServer localHost

$group = "All Computers"

#list of all computers name nad number of updates
$a = Get-PSWSUSUpdateSummaryPerClient | Select-Object "Computer","Needed"
#"Computer" is name value

#list of all computers name and ip
$b = Get-PSWSUSClientsInGroup -Name $group | Select-Object 
"IPAddress","FullDomainName"
#"FullDomainName" is name value

$ab
#merging $a and $b by name value 
return $ab
```

How can i do this as fast and easy as possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of specific questions and answers at StackOverflow on how to merge(/join) a list of of objects in PowerShell.
Unfortunately, there is no native cmdlet solution in PowerShell that can do this "*as fast and easy as possible*", but there are a few cmdlets available for download as e.g. the [Join-Object cmdlet at the PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join/2.2.2/DisplayScript) that can join object lists simular to SQL.

The required command for your question when using the [Join-Object cmdlet](https://github.com/iRon7/Join-Object) will probably as simple as:

```
$ab = $a | Join $b Name
```

Comment: I cant install this on my machine so it is not solution for me

Comment: The complete solution is at https://github.com/iRon7/Join-Object, you can just copy and paste the Join-Object function into your own script (or command host)

Comment: I am having some truble with this join-object script. I would like to save-script it but i am having truble with nuget.exe(newest stable version) i had downloaded it and put in paths that powershell says it should be but it still is not recognized. When i copy the function from file i have some problem with bracets.

Comment: To dot-source a downloaded file, use the syntax: `. path\Join.ps1` (there will be no output, but it should recognize the `Join-Object` (alias `Join`) command after the invocation. To Copy/Paste: Open the [Join-Object.ps1](https://github.com/iRon7/Join-Object/blob/master/Join-Object.ps1) than select [`Raw`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iRon7/Join-Object/master/Join-Object.ps1) (or click on[`Raw`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iRon7/Join-Object/master/Join-Object.ps1)), Select All, Copy and Paste it in. If it still doesn't work, I would suggest to open a new GitHub specific question.

Comment: After i had dot sourced join-object i got error „Function Join-Object + ~ Missing closing ‚}’”. Can you check that you dont have this problem with join object function that is avaliable on link from you?

Comment: Just tested both PowerShell Gallery and GitHub, everything works fine for me. Apparently you didn't correctly download, or copy/paste it.

Comment: Ok it was some weird error. I downloaded it again and now all is fine. Thanks!

Comment: I still have some problem with this. I got list of $a where object looks like this 
"IPAddress      : someIp
FullDomainName : domian.pl
" and $b where it looks like this "                                                                
Computer       : domain.pl
Needed         : 0" how to join then if there is no common named field ?